# Как лучше посылать регулярные обновления страницы пользователю?

Tags: php, javascript

Добрый день. Я хочу написать многопользовательскую настольную браузерную игру. В течении игры пользователю будут постоянно будут приходить обновления от сервера(обработка его хода, действия противников и так далее). 
Как лучше реализовать эти обновления?

Посылать на PHP запросы js'ом(обновилась ли игровая ситуация?).

Посылать с PHP сообщения клиенту когда что-то произойдет? Если это возможно, то мне представялется себе лучшим решением, чем долбать сервер.
Но как это реализовать? Допустим 1 игрок совершил ход, как передать эти данные 2 игроку? Записывать игровую ситуацию в файл и потом как-то при помощи PHP послать ее(обновленную ситуацию) игроку? Если, да - то как?

Спасибо.

Comment: Как на счет websocket'ов ?

Comment: @KirillStoianov Спасибо, почитаю. Звучит как подходящая вещь.